# Execute immediate 'Create or replace view' gives 00900. 00000 - "invalid SQL statement" error

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, execute-immediate

I have been stuck with this error. Can you please suggest what the mistake is in the code below? This is written inside a procedure that takes input for the variables. Thanks.

```
execute immediate 'Create or replace view '||p_viewname||' AS  
     select * from (  
     select NAME, CODETYPE, CODE  
     from HLIDEV_VIEWS.V_CONCEPT  
     WHERE HLIDEV_VIEWS.V_CONCEPT.CONCEPTTYPE = '''||p_concepttype||'''  
    )  
    pivot   
    (  
       max(code)  
       for codetype in ('||all_codetypes||')  
    )';
```

Update: Below is the error I am seeing.

```
EXEC "HLIDEV_VIEWS"."FinalCreatePOAView" ('POA_CONCEPT_TYPE','PresentOnAdmission')
Error report -
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at "HLIDEV_VIEWS.FinalCreatePOAView", line 39
ORA-06512: at line 1
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is perfectly doable using execute immediate.  You just have a syntax error somewhere or the table really doesn't exist.

Try writing the string you are building to DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE instead of sending it to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.  Then, try to run that string as a command in SQL*Plus.  That should highlight the error.

FWIW, I don't have your objects in my database, but I wrote an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with the same form as yours and it works fine in Oracle 11g2.

```
DECLARE  
  p_view_name VARCHAR2(61) := 'VXSMIMMCP.MATT_V';
  p_region_code VARCHAR2(30) := 'R01';
  p_all_port_codes VARCHAR2(400) := '''P01'',''P02'',''P03''';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
       'Create or replace view '
    || p_view_name
    || ' AS select * from ( select REGION_CODE,   account_number , port_code from APPS.XXCUS_ACCOUNTS WHERE APPS.XXCUS_ACCOUNTS.REGION_CODE  = '''
    || p_region_code
    || ''' ) pivot ( min(account_number) for port_code in ('
    || p_all_port_codes
    || ') )' ;
END;
```

Comment: I saved the query to a variable and printed it. Below is what was printed out. And it even executed and created the view when I ran separately.

Create or replace view PresentOnAdmission AS   
    select * from (  
     select NAME, CODETYPE, CODE  
     from HLIDEV_VIEWS.V_CONCEPT  
     WHERE HLIDEV_VIEWS.V_CONCEPT.CONCEPTTYPE =   'POA_CONCEPT_TYPE'  
    )  
    pivot   
    (  
       max(code) as code  
       for (codetype) in ('POA_CODE' AS POA_CODE,'POA_REASON' AS POA_REASON)  
    );

Comment: @PMangu It looks like Syntax error. Try  trial and error method: first remove `pivot` and see any error.Then remove `where` condition and see and finally try removing both and check.This way you should be able to narrow down(debug) to the exact error and correct.

Comment: refer few examples : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#CHDGJEGD

Comment: Are you running the execute immediate from a package?  Does the package owner have SELECT privilege on the table granted directly to him (not through a role)?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I am running this from a stored procedure, not from a package, if that is what you asked. I am running this from my user account (schema I should say) which has admin role assigned. I am not admin user, not in admin group. Just an admin role was created and assigned to me. But if I am able to run and able to create using the same Create view statement separately (not from the stored procedure), then would it be a privilege problem? Just wondering, as I am very bad at these privilege level issues.

Comment: All roles are disabled in named PL/SQL blocks the run with definer's rights.  So, if you are getting your privileges on a table via a role that has been granted to you, it's possible that you can run a SQL directly that you cannot run in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MatthewMcPeak and @MahendarMahi for your inputs. Suddenly my code started working fine and it created the view the way I wanted. The only thing I did was, as @MahendarMahi suggested, I removed pivot and ran it to see the same error and then replaced pivot and the error was gone. I am sure there is no change in the code but anyhow it weirdly works now. Thank you again for your time.